# Move/transform everything from pwd into subdirectory while archiving with tar

Tags: tar, bsd

I am on a MacOS machine (I think tar command is BSD).
From I have read the `-s` switch on BSD tar, is the same thing as the `--transform` switch for GNU tar.

I have this command:

```
tar -zcf foo.tgz -s /^"$(pwd)"/"$(pwd)/package"/ "$(pwd)"
```

what I am trying to do is archive everything into a file called foo.tgz, and put everything into a subdirectory called "package".

I get this error:

> tar: Invalid replacement flag a

I believe what's past to the -s option is not correct, but not sure what it might be.

Ultimately, I am looking to write the output to stdout, not to a file called foo.tgz, so if you feel like updating that too, please do, thanks.

Comment: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&sektion=&n=1

Answer (score 4):

Note the implicit clash between the slash used as the separator for the substitution pattern and replacement, and the slash used as the directory separator. If the current directory is, e.g. `/foo/bar`, the string you're giving to `tar` is

```
/^/foo/bar//foo/bar/package/
```

where `^` is taken as the pattern, `foo` as the replacement, and the rest as flags. Here, I get an error for the `b`:

```
tar: Invalid replacement flag b
```

Luckily, the `tar` on my Mac accepts other characters in place of the slash separator, so you can use, say `~`, which makes it easier to put full pathnames in the pattern. e.g. `-s "~^a$~x/y~"` works and renames `a` to `x/y`.

Backslash-escapes (`\/`, `\057` or `\x2f`) don't seem to work, so you'll need to choose as separator some character you don't need in the patterns themselves.